# How to add a build selector as a parameter?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have two jobs:

1. Build job
2. Deployment job

I copy the artifacts (jars) generated in the first job to the second job and deploy them to an environment.

```
properties([
  parameters(
    [
      string(
        name: 'buildnumber',
        description: 'Buildnumber to deploy'
      ),
      choice(
        name: 'env',
        choices: ['qa', 'stage', 'prod'],
        description: 'Environment where the app should be deployed'
      )
    ]
  )
])

node{

    stage('Copy artifacts'){
          copyArtifacts(projectName: 'my-demo-build-job/master', selector: specific(params.buildnumber))

    }
    stage('Deploy'){
        sh 'Deploying to the specified environment '
    }
}
```

With this I have to manually check the latest/successful builds and put that as a parameter. Is there a way so that we can get a dropdown with all the successful build sorted by build number as a selector from the other job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) for achieving what you want with the help of a groovy script.
You will need to define an extended choice parameter of type *Single Select*, as a Source for Value choose *Groovy Script*, and as a groovy script use something like the following:

```
def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my-demo-build-job/master')
return job.builds.findResults{
    it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS ? it.getNumber().toInteger() : null
}
```

This script will go over all the build of the configured job and filter out only the successful builds - which will be returned as the select-list options for the parameter.
The configuration in the pipeline will look like:

```
properties([
        parameters([
                extendedChoice(name: 'buildnumber', type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Buildnumber to deploy', visibleItemCount: 10, groovyScript:
                        '''def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my-demo-build-job/master')
                           return job.builds.findResults { it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS ? it.getNumber().toInteger() : null }''',
                choice(name: 'env', choices:  ['qa', 'stage', 'prod'], description: 'Environment where the app should be deployed'),
        ])
])
```

Comment: Will the result be sorted in decreasing order of build number?

Comment: Yes it will, as it is already sorted in the `job.builds` list. In addition you can always reverse the order using the `reverse()` function: `job.builds.reverse() ...`

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically show this parameter when another boolean parameter is set to true, otherwise show a different set of parameters?

Comment: Yes that is possible using the [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/), see the example section for using the reactive parameters, in there is an example smilier to what you want.